# vba, outlook, Userform if comebox & text fields

Tags: vba, outlook, userform

I have user form with 1 combobox field and several text fields.
Combobox 1 = type of application (7 different results)
Text field like Name, Surname, Town, Post Code etc.

After pressing Ok button, I would like prompt user if mandatory field is missing.

Mandatory field for 1 selection is field 1, field2 and field3
 for selection 2 only filed 1 and 2 for 3 only field 6 
etc.

Weird thing is that if I select something I didn't define in this sub, I selecting value 4 or 5 I still get message.
What did I miss?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If UserForm2.ComboBox1T.Value = "1.New Application" _
And TextBox1.Text = "" _
Or TextBox2.Text = "" _
Or TextBox3.Text = "" _
Then
MsgBox ("Fill in all mandatory Fields")


Exit Sub
End If


If UserForm2.ComboBox1T.Value = "2.Old Application" _
And TextBox1.Text = "" _
Or TextBox2.Text = "" _
Then
MsgBox ("Fill in all mandatory Fields")

Exit Sub
End If

If UserForm2.ComboBox1T.Value = "3.Somethingelse" _
And TextBox1.Text = "" _
Or TextBox2.Text = "" _
Then
MsgBox ("Fill in all mandatory Fields")


Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Ahh, I know what you miss. You are missing [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for those who spare their valuable time to answer your questions.

Comment: My mistake, all sorted. I just started with stackoverflow and wasn't sure how everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.

```
 With Me 
   Select Case .ComboBox1T 
  Case "1.New Application" 
    If .TB1 = "" Or .TB2 = "" Or .TB3 = ""  Then MsgBox ("Something")

  Case "2.old Application" 
    If .TB1 = "" Or .TB2 = "" Then MsgBox ("Something")

Case "3.Other Application" 
    If ........

Case "4." 
Case "5." 
Case "6." 
Case "7." 


End Select 
End With
```